# In Python Multi mechanize is there a way to print the max value of a variable among all the transactions?

Tags: python

```
def run(self):
    if value > self.value1:
        self.value1 = value
        print('value=%s' %(self.value1))
```

When we are using multi threads the value is getting printed for every Transaction and the last one is not often the max value. I just want the max value to be printed at the end of the run.What is the possible way?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any multithreading.

Comment: Its in the config file 
`[global]
run_time = 5
rampup = 0
results_ts_interval = 10

[user_group-1]
threads = 50
script = sample1.py` @roganjosh